# EditText Lag on Activity Change

Tags: android

I am using Text from an EditText to get some items in a listview using t a custom adapter from a mysql database. On the click of a button next to the EditText , I am starting another activity using intent. The EditText works fine when th app first starts and opens to MainActivity but the cursor remains stagnant for 1-2 seconds when MainActivity is loaded from another acivity.The code is as follows:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="nf.co.riaah.chutte.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#EEEEEE"
android:id="@+id/linear_main">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:theme= "@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="1dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/title"
        android:id="@+id/title_image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/oie_transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/cart_icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/search_area"
    android:padding="5dp">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="Type Your Text Here"
    android:id="@+id/gettext"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:onClick="search_product"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="\?"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="125dp">
        </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="About Us">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/re"
                android:src="@drawable/home_clipart_edited"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="Nearby Shops"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/money_clipart_edited"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="Donate"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:onClick="goto_list">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="Click Here for latest"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText editText;
public static String pname;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // an example activity_main.xml is provided below
    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gettext);
}

public void goto_list(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Search_multiple.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void search_product(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Search_multiple.class);
    pname = editText.getText().toString();
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use asynchronous threads when working with databases, your cursor stops because the second intent starts time consuming operation i.e. fething data from the mysql, on the main thread.

Comment: I am using asynctask for accesing database in Search_multiple.class. Should I be using it for the intent as well?

Comment: @I.Goel just remove everything from the oncreate (opause, onstart, onrestart) of the second activity and check if the cursor stops, if it doesn't recover your code line by line checking where is the exact point when cursor stops

Comment: I just figured that on touching the EditText, the keyboard comes up with no lag, but the cursor remains stagnant for about0.5 to 1 second. Is this normal or am I committing some other mistake.